# Why won't my Silverlight Application load in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0

For some strange reason my Silverlight 4 application isn't loading in Internet Explorer. I see no error messages, just a blank screen. It works fine in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Though I don't really know why this would happen, it might be helpful to someone else if you know whether you installed Silverlight 4 from clean or if it was upgraded from Silverlight 3?

And also how you're hosting your Silverlight app - IIS 6/7, just debugging straight from VS, etc?

Comment: I have seen instances where the control won't start initializing until you click on the area hosting the control. Not sure why it happens, but i've only seen it happen in IE (7 and 8).

Comment: I originally had Silverlight 3 and upgraded to Silverlight 4. However, I have another Silverlight 4 application I created several weeks ago that works fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer, so the problem seems to be in the Silverlight application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why, but the application didn't like one of my div tags. As soon as I pulled it from the div tag, it showed up no problem.

Comment: What exactly was the tag that had an issue? I am having a silver light page lock up in IE but work perfectly fine in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

When SL has failed to load for me in a browser it is usually related to mime-type. It would be worth checking to make sure it is set correctly by the server:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/

Comment: In the IE11 debugger, when the mime type is incorrect, the status will show as (aborted) and 0 bytes loaded.